# Is it possible to use strptime to convert a day of the week to datetime format?

Tags: python, datetime

For instance:

```
time = "Tuesday"
time_final = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%A")
time_final
```

However, the result I get is 1/1/1900, which is a Monday

```
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Well, assuming this would have worked, the date of "what" Tuesday would you expect?

Comment: @DeepSpace Let's say the first Tuesday starting from 1/1/1900, which would be 1/2/1900.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on OP's comment (they want the date of the first specific day starting from 1/1/1900), I'd just brute force it. It also does not require any third-party modules.

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

days = {0: 'Monday', 1: 'Tuesday', 2: 'Wednesday', 3: 'Thursday',
        4: 'Friday', 5: 'Saturday', 6: 'Sunday'}
    
required_day = 'Tuesday'  
start = date(1900, 1, 1)
current_date = start
while days[current_date.weekday()] != required_day:
    current_date += timedelta(days=1)
print(current_date)
```

Outputs

```
1900-01-02
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`dateparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, specifically its [relative dates](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#relative-dates) functionality:

```
>>> from dateparser import parse
>>> parse("Tuesday")
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 6, 0, 0)
```

For the example you mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308609/is-it-possible-to-use-strptime-to-convert-a-day-of-the-week-to-datetime-format/64308634?noredirect=1#comment113716761_64308609):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> parse('Tuesday', settings={'RELATIVE_BASE': datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), 'PREFER_DATES_FROM': 'future'})
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 2, 0, 0)
```

Thanks to [@DeepSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308609/is-it-possible-to-use-strptime-to-convert-a-day-of-the-week-to-datetime-format/64308634?noredirect=1#comment113717222_64308634) for this one.

Comment: You can do `parse('Tuesday', settings={'RELATIVE_BASE': datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), 'PREFER_DATES_FROM': 'future'})` to get the output OP wants