# How to get Difference between two strings with time and weekday in Python

Tags: python, date, parsing, strptime, strftime

I have 2 strings of weekday and time:

```
time_1 = "Wed 09:00"
time_2 = "Fri 13:00"
```

I want to get the time difference between the two times in seconds.

I have tried the `datetime.datetime.strptime` (or `strftime`) but without success.
it does not know how to relate to the weekday.

example:

```
time_1 = strptime(time_1, "%a %H:%M")
time_2 = strptime(time_2, "%a %H:%M")
```

`time_diff = (time_2 - time_1).total_seconds()` does not take into account the weekday, just the hours and minutes.

My case is that I don't parse dates, but weekdays and hours/minutes

Comment: The issue here is ambiguity because Friday comes both after and before Wednesday. To be unambiguous you would need a date

Comment: You might be running into the same issue as described here, where `strptime` can't possibly tell exactly _which_ Wednesday and Friday you're trying to talk about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308609/is-it-possible-to-use-strptime-to-convert-a-day-of-the-week-to-datetime-format . The `dateparser` library described in one of the answers there should give you a decent guess as to the right answer, though Albert is right that it's not clear to the Python interpreter whether you want there to be 2, -5 or even 9 days between Wednesday or Friday.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using dateparse module in python.

Install dateparse module using pip

```
pip install dateparse
```

Import the module and calculate the time difference in seconds

```
from dateparser import parse

time_1 = "Wed 09:00"
time_2 = "Fri 13:00"

time_1 = parse(time_1)
time_2 = parse(time_2)

time_diff = (time_2 - time_1).total_seconds()

print(time_diff)
```

The output of the above code sample is
`187200.0`

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that the week days will always be interpreted as the most recent day in the *past*. If you swapped the definitions of `time_1` and `time_2`, you'll get a negative answer, rather than the 5-day answer you might have expected.